# How to include node module for Babel using Webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, uglifyjs

when running

```
npm run build
```

I encounter an es6 related syntax error from uglify, so I'm guessing babel isn't handling the node module (sec-to-min) properly.

My .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "comments": false,
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [ "istanbul" ]
    }
  }
}
```

My Webpack config:

```
var path = require('path')
var config = require('../config')
var utils = require('./utils')
var projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../')

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV
// check env & config/index.js to decide whether to enable CSS source maps for the
// various preprocessor loaders added to vue-loader at the end of this file
var cssSourceMapDev = (env === 'development' && config.dev.cssSourceMap)
var cssSourceMapProd = (env === 'production' && config.build.productionSourceMap)
var useCssSourceMap = cssSourceMapDev || cssSourceMapProd

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components')
    }
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')]
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: [
          path.join(projectRoot, 'src')
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: [
          path.join(projectRoot, 'src')
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: [
          path.join(projectRoot, 'src'),
          'node_modules/sec-to-min'
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  eslint: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: utils.cssLoaders({ sourceMap: useCssSourceMap }),
    postcss: [
      require('autoprefixer')({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

& the ERR:

> ERROR in static/js/vendor.8d64852626f0513309d9.js from UglifyJs
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>)
>   [./~/sec-to-min/index.js:3,0]

How can I direct babel to compile this module?

Answer (score 8):

please note that on Windows the slashes in the path will be \ so the above solution would have to be changed to `exclude: /node_modules\\(?!(sec-to-min)\/).*/`

This was the solution that worked for me, with webpack 4.3 and babel-loader 8.0.5, and using the recommended @babel/preset-env, adapted from here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031#issuecomment-283517150

```
{
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: [paths.appSrc, paths.appNodeModules],
            exclude: function(modulePath) {
              return (
                /node_modules/.test(modulePath) &&
                !/node_modules\\react-dev-utils/.test(modulePath)
              );
            },
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              compact: true,
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          },
```

I found it helpful to use the function for exclude as I was able to add console logs within the function to check which modules were being matched by the regex.

Comment: `path.join()` is the system agnostic way to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

In babel section of webpack config change to this :

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    include: [
      path.join(projectRoot, 'src')
    ],
    exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(sec-to-min)\/).*/
  }
```

Looks like `exclude` has priority over `include`.

Comment: still no luck, my Webpack is set up in 
    "build/webpack.base.conf.js" are there ever multiple configs?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple versions of webpack configuration file. By default it will look for `webpack.config.json`, if no specific destination is passed. Please find your build command, typically it defined in `scripts` section of package.json and make sure that it's using right config. Example of invocation with config file explicitly set :

webpack --config webpack.config.js

Comment: @KaroCastro-Wunsch also try to add path to your module back to `include` section (i removed it in my answer, maybe it was a mistake).

Answer (score 0):

Install following packages

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
npm install babel-preset-stage-0 --save-dev
```

Add `es2015` and `stage-0` in your babel presets

```
{
   "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"],
}
```

**UPDATE**
Try this

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
       options: {
        presets: ['env', 'react', 'stage-0'],
       },
    },
    include: [
      path.join(projectRoot, 'src'),
      'node_modules/sec-to-min'
    ],
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
```

Comment: Didn't quite do the trick, I added some info! Do you know how to make sure babel targets node modules specifically? Since they're excluded in the Webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me in Webpack v4:

```
rules: [{
    include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    /node_modules\/(dom7|swiper)/
  ],
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {
  'modules': false
  }]]
},
  test: /\.(js)$/
}]
```